# IE8/9 going into error function when webservice response contains Chinese characters

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

Following is my code

```
                $.getJSON('url',function(res){
                pData = res.Response;
                if(pData.Header.Message=='Success')
                {//some CODE

                }else{
                    alert('some error');
                }
            }).error(function(){
                    alert('There is a web service issue...');
});
```

When the webservice conatins chinese characters the IE goes executes error function.on Network tab i can see the response ..also can see the response code 200 ok .. It works perfectly on chrome.happens when only there are chinese characters .. works perfectly for normal responses ...

Comment: What are the HTTP response headers? In particular, what is the `charset` attribute on the `Content-Type` response header? See, for instance, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/02/28/script-error-c00ce56e-means-you-have-specified-an-invalid-charset-utf8-is-not-utf-8.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE appears to trigger failure if it can't parse the response as xml/json/text, even if the request was a success,it calls a error function... In this case because of chinese characters may be IE was not able to parse the respone 
I am now checking response manually and then excuting the required function accordingly.. as i am using jQuery following is the code i am using to chk ststus code

```
statusCode: {200: function() {
              alert( "Success" );
            }
          }
```

into a AJAX function